# "It {cost / costs} a lot to live there"?

Tags: grammar, subject-verb-agreement, present-simple

In the simple present tense, which one is true based on this sentence? And, please explain.

> The food in Japan is expensive. It {**cost / costs**} a lot to live
>   there.

Comment: Why do you think yourself?

Comment: @cardinal Because I try to answer question in my tenses book. I'm learning tenses. do you have other answer maybe ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: One person answered your question, I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Subject and verb must agree in number (singular or plural). The subject "It" is singular. Therefore the verb must also be singular: "costs"